# Determine if user can access database generated page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, roleprovider

I have `Membership`, `Profile` and `Role` providers setup for my .NET MVC website. I would like to say: this `Role` has access to that `Page`.

How do I 'inject' this code to the RoleProvider? Or do I have to override it somehow? Any leads?

*(Roles are stored in the default ASP.NET SqlRoleProvider, Pages are stored in a seperate SQL database).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [using](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/programming-and-development/?p=456) [sitemaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab.aspx) under asp.net.  It is VERY easy to manage and to [extend](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/aspnet2security.aspx).

I have even used them as the datasource for a menu system.

Once in your page, you can do something like:

```
User.IsInRole("RoleName")
```

Comment: Hmmz, i currently have a custom SiteMapProvider. Am I missing something...? :)

Comment: In your custom sitemapprovider code, override the IsAccessibleToUser method and use context.User.IsInRole(role)  - Then in your sitemap, you can add the roles attribute (roles="SysAdmin,Contributor")

Answer (score 2):

Why would you inject this into the role provider?  Why not just decorate the ActionResult `[Authorise(Roles="myrole")]`?

I understand that your pages are in the database but the action result still needs to call the view right?

I guess you could write you're own custom attribute which can check and either grant access or deny it.

I don't think the role provider is the right place for determining whether a page can be displayed or not.

Comment: Lol, I also have a custom FilterAttribute which checks if a user is authorized to view a page. How do I administrate this all? is the question i guess. :)

Comment: By administrate do you mean how do you create roles and assign users to it?  Little confused as to the meaning here sorry @ropstah

Comment: No I can create roles and assign users. I need to 'assign' pages to roles, in a manageable way..

Comment: Ah ok!!!  I just use the .net configuration manager to manage my roles.  Then I guess you'd need a table that has your roles/roleIds and accessible pages/pageId's as a lookup table.  Definately a custom attribute

Comment: You'd obviously need a page that will allow you to assign pages to roles.  maybe a grid type of approach.  there are some great jquery grids out there for that.  or even a folder structure allowing you to select a page and then assign roles to them.